# Datastax Enterprise 5.0 Lifecycle Manager - provisioning fails

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm trying to install Datastax Enterprise 5.0 by using Lifecycle Manager (I've installed Opscenter). But install job fails with a message that is not too descriptive, and obviously pretty rare (0 hits in Google):

Event Type:

```
error-MeldError
```

Result/Message:

```
Meld failed on: name="<nodename>" ssh-management-address="<nodeip>" node-id="<someguid>" job-id="<someguid>" stdout="" stderr=""
```

Stack trace:

```
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$monitor_command.invoke(common.clj:547)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command.invoke(common.clj:701)
lcm.jobs.multinode.install.InstallJob.run(install.clj:315)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_job.invoke(common.clj:71)
lcm.jobs.multinode.common$process_run__18205$fn__18206.invoke(common.clj:89)
clojure.core.async$thread_call$fn__9695.invoke(async.clj:434)
clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4

Java: Oracle Java 8

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It _might_ have something to do with strings not being properly escaped by lifecycle manager. Could you share some of your config like cluster name and such, are you using any special characters in any name / string fields?

Comment: OpsCenter developer here. Hard to tell whats going on from those snippets. Can you post the job-events and opscenterd.log lines leading up to the error for context? Also, I made a proposed edit to your post to add the 'opscenter' tag, which is watched by some of the developers.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Sadly, I can't provide logs you've asked for because I've reinstalled everything by using [Cassandra Puppet module] (https://forge.puppet.com/locp/cassandra). But I can pretty precisely tell you what I've tried:

Comment: - Ubuntu 14.04 vanila, with complete distro-upgrade;
- Oracle Java 8 from [WebUpd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java);
- OpsCenter from apt repository.

I've set `root` user account for SSH, with password (no cert). I can confirm that the account has SSH access (I've tried with putty).